# Does Spring Boot GZIP static resources only once?

Tags: optimization, spring-boot, gzip

I already have gzip turned on for spring boot embedded server. My concern is how spring boot handles the gzip of static resources. Since these do not change, does spring boot (or the underlying embedded server) run the gzip algorithm once then caches the result? It just seems to be a waste of processing power to run the gzip algo on every request for a static resource.

Answer (score 2):

The `GzipResourceResolver` looks for `*.gz` files in your resource directory, which you must prepare at build time. It does not gzip the resources on the fly, which addresses your concerns, I think.

The main docs do not directly cover this: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content

You can configure this by

1) At build time, create gzip copies of all your static files, e.g. by:

```
gzip --keep --best -r src/main/resources/public
```

2) Configure spring, by adding a class like:

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry
          .addResourceHandler("/**")
          .addResourceLocations("/public/")
          .resourceChain(true) // cache resource lookups
          .addResolver(new GzipResourceResolver())
          .addResolver(new PathResourceResolver());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use the Spring `ResourceResolver` specifically around caching, the [`CachingResourceResolver`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/resource/CachingResourceResolver.html). Your configuration should be something along the lines of this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableCaching
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private CacheManager cacheManager;


    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry
          .addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
          .addResourceLocations("/resources/")
          .setCachePeriod(3600)  // Browser cache
          .resourceChain(true)
          .addResolver(new CachingResourceResolver(cacheManager, "resourceCache"))
          .addResolver(new GzipResourceResolver())
          .addResolver(new PathResourceResolver());
    }
}
```

The important thing is that the CacheManager has to be configured for the application so check out the [Spring Boot Caching docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-caching.html) for more info (probably best for a local cache using Caffeine).

Comment: Did you test this? I don't think this will work; see my answer.